# Changing a Classic Singleton for use with .NET Core 3.1 and DependencyInjection (DI)

Tags: c#, singleton, settings

I have the following class which I would like to use in .NET Core with DI

```
public class DefaultSettingsProvider : ISettingsProvider
{
    private static DefaultSettingsProvider _instance = null;
    private string _fileName = "blundergat.settings";

    private DefaultSettingsProvider() { }

    public static DefaultSettingsProvider Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new DefaultSettingsProvider();
                if (File.Exists(_instance.GetSerializedFilePath()))
                {
                    DefaultSettingsProvider o = _instance.Deserialize();
                    _instance = o ?? _instance;
                }
                _instance.RestoreDefaults();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        (this as ICustomXmlSerializableObject).Serialize();
    }

    public string GetSerializedFilePath()
    {
        return Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, _fileName);
    }

    public void RestoreDefaults(bool force = false)
    {
        if (DataSourceSettings == null || force)
            DataSourceSettings = new DataSourceSettings();

        if (IcpSolverSettings == null || force)
            IcpSolverSettings = new IcpSolverSettings();
    }

    [XmlElement, Browsable(false)]
    public DataSourceSettings DataSourceSettings { get; set; }

    [XmlElement, Browsable(false)]
    public IcpSolverSettings IcpSolverSettings { get; set; }
}
```

With

```
public interface ISettingsProvider : ICustomXmlSerializableObject
{
    void Save();

    void RestoreDefaults(bool force = false);
}
```

Where I configure the DI via

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddSingleton<IHostedService, CoreHostingService>()
    .AddSingleton<ISolverManagementService, SolverManagementService>()
    .AddSingleton<IDepthMapToPointCloudAdapter, DepthMapToPointCloudAdapter>()
    .AddSingleton<IIcpBatchSolverService, IcpBatchSolverService>()
    .AddSingleton<ISettingsProvider, DefaultSettingsProvider>()
    .AddLogging(builder =>
    {
        builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace); 
        builder.AddSerilog(Log.Logger);
    })
    .BuildServiceProvider();
```

This clearly will not work as I require so I have attempted to change the class to this

```
public class DefaultSettingsProvider : ISettingsProvider
{
    private static DefaultSettingsProvider instance = null;
    private string _fileName = "blundergat.settings";

    public DefaultSettingsProvider()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
            if (File.Exists(instance.GetSerializedFilePath()))
            {
                DefaultSettingsProvider o = instance.Deserialize();
                instance = o ?? instance;
            }
            instance.RestoreDefaults();
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        (this as ICustomXmlSerializableObject).Serialize();
    }

    public string GetSerializedFilePath()
    {
        return Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, _fileName);
    }

    public void RestoreDefaults(bool force = false)
    {
        if (DataSourceSettings == null || force)
            DataSourceSettings = new DataSourceSettings();

        if (IcpSolverSettings == null || force)
            IcpSolverSettings = new IcpSolverSettings();
    }

    [XmlElement, Browsable(false)]
    public DataSourceSettings DataSourceSettings { get; set; }

    [XmlElement, Browsable(false)]
    public IcpSolverSettings IcpSolverSettings { get; set; }
}
```

This works well with DI, however, this does not initialize the settings correctly due to my use of the static `instance", so when I attempt to do

```
public A(ISettingsProvider sp)
{
    string someSetting = sp.DataSouceSettings.DataPath;
}
```

`DataSouceSettings` is null as it is not intialized. How can I align the `instance.DataSouceSettings` with the `sp.DataSouceSettings`? Essentially, how can I amend this class to work with DI, but also operate the way it did with the classic singleton pattern?

Ps. For completeness.

```
[Serializable]
public class DataSourceSettings
{
    public DataSourceSettings()
    {
        BaseDirectory = String.Empty;
    }

    [XmlElement, Browsable(false)]
    public string BaseDirectory { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are already adding it to the DI as a singleton so I don't see a point keeping the singleton code in the class implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have an instance of the singleton just add it instead of letting DI to manage new instance's lifetime - [AddService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddSingleton__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection___0_):

```
  .AddSingleton<ISettingsProvider>(DefaultSettingsProvider.Instance)
```

Comment: Ah, so simple. Thanks for your time.

Comment: That will force the instance to be created during the startup process. If you want to delay that; `.AddSingleton<ISettingsProvider>(p => DefaultSettingsProvider.Instance)`

Comment: What is the best way to unit test with Mocks (Moq) but without parameterless ctor?